# CompletableFuture is a Monad. But where is the Applicative?

Tags: java, monads, completable-future, applicative

Java's `CompletableFuture` is a Monad given its methods `thenCompose` and `thenApply`, which
correspond to `>>=` (bind) and `fmap` in Haskell.

It is a well [known fact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58789006/how-to-define-apply-in-terms-of-bind) that any Monad gives rise to an Applicative. Now, does `CompletableFuture` have a method that corresponds to `<*>` (ap) in Haskell or can such a function be implemented in terms of the existing methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CompletableFuture` does not have a method that directly corresponds to `<*>` in Haskell. However it can be derived by
translating the corresponding Haskell code for turning a Monad into an Applicative:

```
(<*>) :: Monad f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
(<*>) f a = f >>= (`fmap`a )
```

In adaption of Java's terminology, let's call this function `alsoApply` in Java:

```
static <T, R> CompletableFuture<R> alsoApply(CompletableFuture<T> future, CompletableFuture<Function<T, R>> f) {
    return f.thenCompose(future::thenApply);
}
```

With this we can now do

```
CompletableFuture<String> future = alsoApply(
    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "a"),
    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "b")
.thenApply(b -> a -> a + b));

assertEquals("ab", future.get());
```

, which causes the two futures returning "a" and "b" respectively to run in parallel on different threads.