# Java CompletableFuture allOf approach

Tags: java, concurrency, parallel-processing, future, completable-future

I am trying to run 3 operations in parallel using the CompletableFuture approach. Now these 3 operations return different types so need to retrieve the data separately. Here is what i am trying to do:

```
CompletableFuture<List<A>> aFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync (() -> getAList());
CompletableFuture<Map<String,B> bFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync (() -> getBMap());
CompletableFuture<Map<String,C> cFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync (() -> getCMap());

CompletableFuture<Void> combinedFuture =
                    CompletableFuture.allOf (aFuture, bFuture, cFuture);

combinedFuture.get(); (or join())

List<A> aData = aFuture.get(); (or join)
Map<String, C> bData = bFuture.get(); (or join)
Map<String, C> cData = cFuture.get(); (or join)
```

This does the job and works but i am trying to understand if we need to do these gets/joins on combined future as well as individual ones and if there is a better way to do this.

Also i tried using then whenComplete() approach but then the variables i want to assign the returned data are inside the method so i am getting a "The final local variable cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type in Java" error and i don't want to move them to the class level.

looking for some expert/alternate opinions. Thank you in advance

SG

Comment: If you really are retrieving the results of all three CompletableFutures in the same place, one after another, then there is no need for CompletableFuture.allOf.  Calling all three `get()` methods effectively will wait for them all to complete anyway.

Comment: Thanks, How else to do it if we are using ofAll to get the results? I can use the thenApply option because of variable scope mentioned above

Comment: Just remove the creation and use of `combinedFuture`.  It is not needed.  Simply calling `get()` on each of the individual futures is sufficient.  Waiting for them one at a time will guarantee all of them have finished.

Comment: Thanks. Yes but if i want to use the allOf, how would i retrieve the data from the futures in that case?

Comment: The only way to get individual futures’ return values is to keep references to the individual futures, so you can call their get() methods.  The object returned by allOf does not provide any way to access the individual constituent futures.

Comment: Thanks. Yes thats why i have no choice but to do the gets on them. The other alternative is to do whenComplete to make it concise but that will do the same get/joins on the individual futures and also can’t use method local variables.

Comment: Is there a reason you don’t want to call `get()` for each future?

Comment: Are you suggesting to do just that instead of calling allOf? The reason is when we do that the futures are not going to be invoked until the get() is called no? If i understand correctly, allOf() call helps grouping them which we can then use the get/join to get the individual results upon completion. Do you see it done any other way?

Comment: Are you suggesting we don't need allOf call and instead just do get/join on the Futures?

Comment: Yes, I’m saying that calling each future’s get(), one at a time, will effectively do the same thing as waiting for the result of allOf.  In both cases, every future will have completed.

Comment: VGR already addressed, but there are a few caveats. If you want ALL the futures to be completed before you do ANYTHING, then you need to call `allOf(......).get()`, then you must call `get()` for each of the 3 futures. However, if you merely want each future to be completed before it is processed (while also allowing the other, unreached futures to continue in the background), then you just do what @VGR said.

Comment: You can use the "hidden Applicative" to run multiple futures in parallel and collect individual results when all completed. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70724491/402428

Answer (score 2):

Calling `get` or `join` just implies “wait for the completion”. It has no influence of the completion itself.

When you call `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> getAList())`, this method will submit the evaluation of the supplier to the [common pool](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#commonPool()) *immediately*. The caller’s only influence on the execution of `getAList()` is the fact that the JVM will terminate if there are no non-daemon threads running. This is a common error in simple test programs, incorporating a `main` method that doesn’t wait for completion. Otherwise, the execution of `getAList()` will complete, regardless of whether its result will ever be queried.

So when you use

```java
CompletableFuture<List<A>> aFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> getAList());
CompletableFuture<Map<String,B>> bFuture=CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> getBMap());
CompletableFuture<Map<String,C>> cFuture=CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> getCMap());

List<A> aData = aFuture.join();
Map<String, B> bData = bFuture.join();
Map<String, C> cData = cFuture.join();
```

The three subsequent `supplyAsync` calls ensure that the three operations might run concurrently. The three `join()` calls only wait for the result and when the third `join()` returned, you know that all three operations are completed. It’s possible that the first `join()` returns at a time when `aFuture` has been completed, but either or both of the other operations are still running, but that doesn’t matter for three independent operations.

When you execute `CompletableFuture.allOf(aFuture, bFuture, cFuture).join();` before the individual `join()` calls, it ensures that all three operations completed before the first individual `join()` call, but as said, it has no impact when all three operations are independent and you’re not relying on some side effect of their execution (which you shouldn’t in general).

The actual purpose of `allOf` is to construct a new future when you do *not* want to wait for the result immediately. E.g.

```java
record Result(List<A> aData, Map<String, B> bData, Map<String, C> cData) {}
```

```java
CompletableFuture<Result> r = CompletableFuture.allOf(aFuture, bFuture, cFuture)
    .thenApply(v -> new Result(aFuture.join(), bFuture.join(), cFuture.join()));
// return r or pass it to some other code...
```

here, the use of `allOf` is preferable to, e.g.

```java
CompletableFuture<Result> r = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
    () -> new Result(aFuture.join(), bFuture.join(), cFuture.join()));
```

because the latter might block a worker thread when `join()` is called from the supplier. The underlying framework might compensate when it detects this, e.g. start a new thread, but this is still an expensive operation. In contrast, the function chained to `allOf` is only evaluated after all futures completed, so all embedded `join()` calls are guaranteed to return immediately.

For a small number of futures, there’s still an alternative to `allOf`, e.g.

```java
var r = aFuture.thenCompose(a ->
            bFuture.thenCombine(cFuture, (b, c) -> new Result(a, b, c)));
```