# Idiomatic way of comparing results of two completableFutures with assertj

Tags: completable-future, assertj

There are 2 completable futures `cf1` and `cf2` defined as follows:

```
CompletableFuture<Boolean> cf1 = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(true);

CompletableFuture<Boolean> cf2 = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(true);
```

Technically, one could do:

```
var result1 = cf1.get();
var result2 = cf2.get();

assertThat(result1).isEqualTo(result2);
```

For example, if there was only one future, we could do the following:

```
assertThat(cf1)
    .succeedsWithin(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
    .isEqualTo(true);
```

Is there a more idiomatic way to compare the two futures against each other? Note that while the example here uses `CompletableFuture<Boolean>`, the `Boolean` can be replaced with any class.

Comment: It probably depends on what you'd like to verify with cf2. For example, is it just about its value or also that cf2 succeeds within a certain threshold?

Comment: @StefanoCordio For the simplest case, just compare for equality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about composing the two futures into one that completes successfully with a value of `true` if and only if both individual futures complete successfully with the same value? You could e.g. use `thenCompose` followed by `thenApply`:

```
CompletableFuture<Boolean> bothEqual = cf1.thenCompose(b1 -> cf2.thenApply(b2 -> b1 == b2));
```

If the sequential execution from this solution is problematic, you can parallelize by implementing a helper function `alsoApply` and use that one instead of `thenCompose`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70724491/402428) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested only in value comparison, passing `cf2.get()` as argument of `isEqualTo` should be enough:

```
CompletableFuture<Boolean> cf1 = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(true);
CompletableFuture<Boolean> cf2 = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(true);

assertThat(cf1)
  .succeedsWithin(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
  .isEqualTo(cf2.get());
```

The only downside is that `get()` can potentially throw `ExecutionException` and `InterruptedException` so they need to be declared in the test method signature.

If type-specific assertions are needed, [`succeedsWithin(Duration, InstanceOfAssertFactory)`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractCompletableFutureAssert.html#succeedsWithin(java.time.Duration,org.assertj.core.api.InstanceOfAssertFactory)) can help:

```
assertThat(cf1)
  .succeedsWithin(Duration.ofSeconds(1), InstanceOfAssertFactories.BOOLEAN)
  .isTrue(); // hardcoded check to show type-specific assertion
```

Comment: Thanks, Stefano. The downside that you mention is the exact thing that I'm trying to avoid.  I would like to avoid `.get()`. For a simple boolean, hard-coding to `.isTrue()` (or false) is possible, but as I said, I'm comparing two objects here.